# jQuery to select nested tables with a specific class

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery I'm trying to find all tables from third level onwards who has the class myClass applied.

I've been checking the jQuery selectors http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp and looks like it is possible I just can't really make the syntax right.

Comment: Would be great if you can share your dom and script which you have tried.

Comment: like => `$('table table table.myClass');`

Comment: thanks, answers below helped to find the correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> $('table:eq(2) .myclass') 
>$('table table table .myclass')
> 
> <table>
>         <tr>
>             <td>
>                  <span class="myclass">aaaa</span>
>                 <table>
>                     <tr>
>                         <td>
>                              <span class="myclass">bbb</span>
>                             <table>
>                                 <tr>
>                                     <td>
>                                         <span class="myclass">cccc</span>
>                                     </td>
>                                 </tr>
>                             </table>
>                         </td>
>                     </tr>
>                 </table>
>             </td>
>         </tr>
>     </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With HTMl like this:

```
<table>
 <table>
  <table>
   <table class="myClass"> ....
```

or

```
<table>
 <table>
  <table class="myClass"> ....
```

Selector would be:

```
$('.myClass');
```

If all have the same class and you want the 4th one:

```
<table class="myClass">
 <table class="myClass">
  <table class="myClass">
   <table class="myClass"> ....
```

Selector would be:

```
$('table table table .myClass');
```

Comment: Thanks but can I say from 2nd table onwards?

Comment: What do you mean by "from 2nd table onwards"? you have to start somewhere with a jQuery selector, if there is no specific target, that you start at the very top.